# web app runs slow in firefox what can cause this - YUI/Javascript

Tags: javascript, yui

I am building a web app in one page. I am using YUI for stuff like event triggers. The HTML Dom is not that big 50k, Their are a load of script includes for YUI and other stuff. It all loads fine - runs super quick in chrome.
The app is making NO external calls such as url fetching/ajax etc.
My problem is that in Firefox the Dom is sluggish/very slow. even when clicking a button it stays pressed down for a moment then pops up, ie the Dom is slowed down as if something is slowing it down in the background.
I was wondering what might cause this.
Could this be caused by too much code, too complex objects - ie json objects, too many event handlers, or too much Dom access as a whole. It is not the case that the code runs slow. Its not the code itself. It's the issue that the Dom itself is slow, as if their is just too-much code etc. Although most frameworks are hefty I can't see that my code is that large.
Any ideas or pointers would be helpful. I appreciate with no code or an example i can't get exact answers what i was looking for was pointers regarding what is and is not acceptable

1. size of page
2. number of events on Dom
3. complexity of json/JavaScript objects
4. lots of css class selectors in elements ie class="button babel ui red round disabled trigger"

will these things slow the Dom and if so how does one work around it.

Comment: Do you have Firebug enabled in Firefox? I remember it being a significant performance drain.

Comment: yes and if i disable it makes little difference.

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround for this? I'm also experiencing the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Firebug to see where the JavaScript is getting hung up.

1. Open Firebug.
2. Click on "Console".
3. To begin profiling, click "Profile".
4. In your application, click a button you know is slow to respond and wait for the response.
5. Click on "Profile" again.

This will give you a listing of all the JavaScript that executed and which functions took the longest.  This is a good starting place for figuring out why things are taking so long.  It could be that YUI is able to leverage faster DOM selectors in Chrome than FF.  If that is the case, you could probably stand to add some IDs to the page to cut this down.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I'd order your listed parameters as biggest performance draings like this:

1. lots of class selectors
2. number of events on Dom itself
3. complexity of JS/JSON objects
4. page size

But I also use Chrome in development so I wouldn't know for sure.